# Can I process video using flash?

Tags: flash, video-streaming, video-processing

I want to have a web page where user can activate his/her web-camera and send video to another user. Additionally to that I want to have a possibility to process video on the client side. In more details, I want to have a program which analyze video on the client side. Is it possible to do it with Flash?

Answer (score 0):

On the first part of your question:

You can do this, but you need a streaming server. Adobe Flash Media Server, Red5 or Wowza.

On processing video:

The flash plugin is a resources hog as is, don't you think that would be a bit too much for the client?

Comment: Where should I have the "streaming server"? On the client side or on the server side? Such site as "chatroulette" use Flash and P2P streaming (so there is not server) and clients can stream video to each other without streaming server.

Comment: P2P streaming won't work on every network i.e. firewalls and network settings will affect it. That's the problem a streaming server would solve. And as the name suggests, it sits on the server.
If you don't care about that see this: http://thisislike.com/adobe-stratus-software/about